# jQuery backgroundPosition conditional statement

Tags: jquery

I have this here:

```
if($("a#type").css('backgroundPosition') == '0px -40px')
//do something
```

Which passes fine in *Chrome/Safari* but not in *Firefox 4*. Is this a bug in jQuery? Has anyone else come across this? Is there a solution?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. What is the value of `$("a#type").css('backgroundPosition')` at the time? (BTW `a#type` is pointless, just use #type - its much faster).

Comment: might it be `background-position`

Comment: What is the returned value in firefox 4? did you `console.log` it?

Comment: @experimentX background-position same result as stated by @James Wiseman. @James Wiseman the value of $("a#type").css('backgroundPosition') starts off as being 0px -40px. @Shrikant Sharat must read up on console.log'ing it, though the issue is the condition never passes in FF4.

Answer (score 0):

I think the syntax is like this:

```
if($("a#type").css('background-position') == '0px -40px')
```